# Bluetooth to wifi pass through, not tethering, and not wifi to bluetooth

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-bluetooth, obd-ii, pass-through

Im wondering if there's a way of bridging or using a 'pass-thru' to send data from a bluetooth connected device over wifi to another android device.

The real world scenario is; 
I have a bluetooth OBD device (for reading your car specs in real-time)
This connects fine over bluetooth to my android phone running any OBD software.
But i also have an android based in car unit (gps, reversing cam, etc) but oddly enough it doesn't have a bluetooth radio/chip in it, only wifi.

So im wondering if it would be possible to run an app on the car unit and my phone to 'in essence' pass on the bluetooth data. Emulating a bluetooth radio on the car unit.

I know it can be done in reverse for tethering a data connection over bluetooth, but why not the other way around?

Other situations could be sharing a bluetooth device connected to one phone over wifi to many different phones???

Sounds plausible to me, but you guys are the experts!
What say you?

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for http://superuser.com/ or http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip